# Elasticsearch Aggregation over indexed list is out of order and deduplicated

Tags: elasticsearch

When I've indexed `nums`, a list of floats, I expect that aggregations have access to that exact data. Instead, what I'm seeing is that `doc['nums']` is behaving more like a set. That is, it de-duplicates elements from my list and sorts them in ascending order. Any workarounds?

```bash
#! /bin/sh

# Delete the index
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/test"

# Insert a document with one field -- a list of floats
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/doc/1?refresh=true" -d '{
  "nums": [5.0, 3.5, 3.5, 1.0]
}'

# Expected:
# aggregations.foobar.value == [5.0, 3.5, 3.5, 1.0]

# Actual:
# aggregations.foobar.value == [1.0, 3.5, 5.0]
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -d '{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {},
    "aggregations": {
        "foobar": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "_agg[\"numList\"] = []",
                "map_script": "if (doc != null) { _agg.numList.add(doc[\"nums\"].getValues()) }",
                "combine_script": "return _agg.numList",
                "reduce_script": "return _aggs.flatten()"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'deduplication' is happening not because of the aggregation, but earlier - at the index phase. As long as the field is being mapped as "float", it will behave like a set of numbers and remove duplicates. 
The only way to save duplicates in aggregation is to reference the `_source` of the document, given that it was stored

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "foobar": {
            "terms": {
                "script": "groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(_source.nums)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```